# Hot to get the `this` from a class within it's decorator

Tags: typescript

I Have a typescript class decorator, and i need to inject a class instance on a Singleton, so far what i have is:

```js
// provider.decorator.ts
import Injector from './injector';

export default function Provider<T extends { new (...args: any[]): {} }>(
    constructor: T
) {
    Injector.register('scope', constructor);
    return class extends constructor {};
}

// Very first instantiated class on the project
@Provider
export class ThoughtsInfraStack extends cdk.Stack {
    constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);
        const dynamo = new DynamoTables();
    }
}
```

This doesn't work because the constructor is not the class instance

What i could do is on the `ThoughtInfraStack` call my Singleton and inject `this`, but i would really like to do that with a decorator;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the constructor of the class and add your injection logic there :

```
function Provider<T extends { new(...args: any[]): {} }>(
    konstructor: T
) {
    const klass = class extends konstructor {
        constructor(...args: any[]) {
            super(args)
            Injector.register('scope', this);
        }
    }

    return klass;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=23&ssc=1&pln=11&pc=1#code/LAKAxg9gdgzgLgAgJJQFYFMxwgJwQXgQG9QEyEd0BzAS3nRwC4EAzAVyixugQAooAhgFt0zeDhpQqAGgQQARqmZEAvgEpipctsiwIAG3QA6fRCq8ARJVr1KAEwtqt2srvgJEhVQgEwfUAE8AbmcXOABtQREAXQI5RRCQF3IAeUVMOCNfGBoqKF44AAs6WTg1RO0VUCqQUHZOOG4oBAAFHAgANxo7BgAeABUEdAAPOHQoOz8iBCh0AHdeIyWBHCoYZgFA8Oi1ZRUEFQA+XlCAa2hxNixcZn7QDRIk8jdEU-1suLB3mD8RsYm-OdYHAcFdsHhHslXBcQWDcItlqt1v4AtsHqEoQgYGwAA4MXgrNZOJ6YsgoDDXHBGax0MY4XgAchgkDxDNKxRg5Qx5BqlVAoUocDYOGab2yiRqoAAAm1Ot0GKAvh8AGIQCCaEkIF6gym8HFseT6GhgLFiEGSKgPA7VfngGGsOKzOYIVUQSwCRyJRUXAzGUzmckZXBqIA)

Comment: This sounds really smart, but i didn't be able to make it work, the only difference from my project to the one on your playground is that my class `Foo` extends a different class, and it requires some constructor props to be passed through the call of `super`, then whey i try to use the registered scope, i got an error saying that the scope doesn't extend the `cdk.Construct` which is what my original class needs to extend

Comment: Actually, it seems to be more related to AWS-cdk than to typescript, as your solution worked pretty well when not using cdk